# No space left on device Oracle Linux

Tags: disk, inode

My Oracle Linux Machine is complaining that there is no space left on device. I ran some commands to see disk utilization and Inode utilization. Can anyone tell me if this looks right? dev/sda2 doesn't seem to have any Inodes at all.

```
[fatty@oralinux ~]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.9G  206M  1.7G  12% /run
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda2        15G   13G  1.6G  90% /
/dev/vda1       497M  328M  169M  66% /boot
tmpfs           370M     0  370M   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs           370M     0  370M   0% /run/user/1001
[fatty@oralinux ~]$
[fatty@oralinux ~]$
[fatty@oralinux ~]$ df -i
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
devtmpfs       468704   352 468352    1% /dev
tmpfs          472674     1 472673    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          472674  9146 463528    2% /run
tmpfs          472674    15 472659    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda2           0     0      0     - /
/dev/vda1      512000   369 511631    1% /boot
tmpfs          472674     1 472673    1% /run/user/0
tmpfs          472674     1 472673    1% /run/user/1001
[fatty@oralinux ~]$
```

```
[ ~]$ lsblk --fs 
NAME        FSTYPE    LABEL     UUID                    MOUNTPOINT 
sr0         iso9660   cidata    2018-08-31-20-55-08-00 
vda 
├─vda1      xfs       /boot     c9cf52e1-ca900          /boot
└─vda2      btrfs     btr_pool  0d127ec75de7            /
```

Comment: Which filesystem type are you using on `/dev/vda2` (you might use `lsblk --fs` to check)? Some filesystem types can automatically generate inodes on-demand as long as there is free disk space, so the concept of a limited number of inodes doesn't apply to them. One way to indicate this is to show all zeroes in the `df -i` listing.

Comment: [ ~]$ lsblk --fs

NAME   FSTYPE  LABEL    UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT

sr0    iso9660 cidata   2018-08-31-20-55-08-00  
             
`vda `                                                         
`├─vda1 xfs     /boot    c9cf52e1-ca900 /boot`   
`└─vda2 btrfs   btr_pool 0d127ec75de7 /`

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the `lsblk --fs` output into your original question, so that it can be formatted in a easily readable way. In StackExchange, the recommended practice is to edit any extra information requested into the original question, as the comments are not necessarily permanent.

Answer (score 1):

According to the `lsblk --fs` output, your `/dev/vda2` contains a `btrfs` filesystem.

It is a modern filesystem that can create inodes automatically on-demand and has no limitations for the number of inodes, other than available disk space. That's why tracking the number of inodes does not really make sense for the `btrfs` filesystem type, and so it returns all zeroes for any inode statistics queries.

The XFS filesystem (like the `/boot` filesystem on your `/dev/vda1` disk device) can also create inodes on-demand, but there is a limit that is set at filesystem creation time, expressed as a percentage of total filesystem capacity. The default limit allows 25% of the filesystem capacity to be inodes, which means a huge number of tiny files. This limit `imaxpct` can be checked with the `xfs_info` command on a system that uses XFS as the root filesystem:

```
# xfs_info /
meta-data=/dev/mapper/vgsys-root isize=512    agcount=4, agsize=488192 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=1        finobt=1, sparse=0, rmapbt=0
         =                       reflink=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=1952768, imaxpct=25     <--- Here!
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0, ftype=1
log      =internal log           bsize=4096   blocks=2560, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
```

Because of this, on an XFS filesystem the inode statistics can still be meaningful, although it takes a fairly special situation for them to become important. If the current total number of inodes on a XFS filesystem is reached, and the number is still less than the percentage limit set by the `imaxpct` value, and there is free disk space, the total number of inodes on an XFS filesystem will simply grow automatically.

But your XFS filesystem is `/boot`, which usually has a very limited number of files, so about the only way this problem might apply to you if you had somehow accidentally copied a huge number of tiny files to `/boot`, and it does not look like that right now.

### The actual "no space left on device" error

Your `df -h` and `df -i` outputs look fine to me. But on `btrfs` they may not always tell the whole story. Depending on which version of `btrfs-progs` is used on your system, there are two commands that might provide extra information on disk space available on a `btrfs` filesystem.

With `btrfs-progs` older than version 3.18:

```
btrfs fi df /
```

With `btrfs-progs` version 3.18 or newer:

```
sudo btrfs fi usage /
```

`btrfs` is a complex filesystem that essentially includes the functionality of LVM and software RAID, so its disk space allocation can be more complicated that the regular `df` command can display.

For more information, please see the BTRFS Wiki:
https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#or_My_filesystem_is_full.2C_and_I.27ve_put_almost_nothing_into_it.21

If the btrfs-specific commands mentioned above indicate that you're in fact running out of space on your root filesystem, this webpage might be helpful:

https://ohthehugemanatee.org/blog/2019/02/11/btrfs-out-of-space-emergency-response/

Basically, you might need to run `btrfs balance start /` probably with the `-dusage=<some percentage value>` option to minimize the time and the amount of write operations required. But if your BTRFS is already out of usable space, you won't be able to run that command. In that case, you may need to extend the filesystem to another disk device first.